# Elasticsearch audit user activity with basic licence

Tags: elasticsearch

Do you know the how to journal user activity in elasticsearch?
I have a basic licence and turned-on security.
Can I observe somehow/somewhere the user activity within logs/indices?

I found security auditing is part of Premium/Gold License, but is there a way how to do that without purchasing the License?

I tried NGINX proxy , but it can log only IP address.

Comment: I think the answer is no!

Comment: You can have part of the information with slowlogs by settings trace at 0s. You can also use beats to log more information.

Comment: @Jaycreation interesting idea, I will  try it.

Comment: @Jaycreation do you have experience with slowlog setup? Based on documents "If a call was initiated with an X-Opaque-ID header, then the user ID is included in Search Slow logs as an additional id field" 
this is only User info I found, however I was not able to report the slowlog with this ID. ID field is always empty. 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/index-modules-slowlog.html

Comment: so we resolved the problem by the following setup
I kept Kibana in http (not https)
and I installed packetbeat to monitor all user traffic on 5601 
then I filter/parse the user interaction with kibana